# Confusion around styled-component styling in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm a bit confused about all the ways you can style using Material UI. My objective is to have one styling API through out the app. However, it would be nice to have some styled-components-like styles for some global components.

Material-UI exposed an API to achieve this. This is refered to as a styled-components-way-to-do-it even though the implementation is quite different from the "real" styled-components library(?):

```
const MyButton = styled(Button)({
    background: 'linear-gradient(...)',
});
```

Another API you can find in the documentation in this one (may only serve to overwrite classes of MUI components):

```
const BootstrapInput = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    'label + &': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  },
}))(InputBase);
```

Both of these implementations don't allow me to access the `theme`.

I would really like to have a way to style a simple div (or any other native element) as a component (like styled-components) but also have the ability to access the `theme`.

Is that at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

I like the [hook](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) version, which is really simple.

```
const useStyles = makeStyle(theme => ({ /* all of your css goodies */ }));

const myComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles(/* can pass in props here if you need to */)
    return <div className={classes.divCss}>Hi</div>
}
```

[withStyles](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles) takes a function as well that you can use to access the theme, e.g., `withStyles(theme => ({ ... }))`

The documentation for MUI can be a little hit and miss, but it's mostly hit. Should spend some more time there for this stuff.

Comment: Ok, yeah - this is what I've been using thus far. I now found myself really wishing for a way to have easiy component level styling.